# Invoke-Command error

Tags: powershell

I have the following  Powershell script

```
$se1 = New-Pssession  -computerName .
$service = "Myservice"  
Invoke-Command -session $se1 -scriptblock { Stop-Service -displayname  $service   } 
Remove-PSSession  $se1
```

It fails with the error

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DisplayName' because it is null
```

It seems to be the value of $service is passed when the cmdlet is executed.

Any hints to resolve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to the script block.  It won't expand variables in the script block until it's executed at the remote system, and that local variable doesn't exist there.

```
$se1 = New-Pssession  -computerName .
$service = "Myservice"  
Invoke-Command -session $se1 -scriptblock { Stop-Service -displayname  $args[0]  }  -argumentlist $service
Remove-PSSession  $se1
```

The argument list will get passed to the remote system along with the script block.